# How to use scanner to produce one single String from a txt file in java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Here is the data that I am extracting from a txt:

```
1|Fred|Fish|fredfish@gamer.net|Ithroeann|19770322
2|Laurie|Nash|laurieeenash@gmail.com|Mazzzap|19820828
3|Conrad|Washington|fredfish@gamer.net|Crayonbreath|19720712
```

Here is the code for scanner to read the content from the txt:

```
   File file = new File("players.txt");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            s.close();
```

I was wondering is there any way to merge each individual line from the scanner into a single string output.

The string output will then be used by my other method to split it into different player objects.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use concatanation `+`.

Comment: that is performance kill

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object of `StringBuilder`. As you fetch a line from the file you can use its `append()` method. Once you read and append all the lines you can get the `String` object by invoking `toString()` on the object of `StringBuilder`.

Also note that you can use `+` on Simple `String` objects but as objects of class `String` are immutable hence doing so will result in lot of `String` objects which will be a performance kill. Hence `StringBuilder` is preferably better choice.